# datagridview can't set rows height when AutoSizeRowsMode is AllCells

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I can't set row height when `AutoSizeRowsMode` is `AllCells`.

If `AutoSizeRowsMode` is `None`, everything works fine. I can set it.

But I have to use `AllCells` `AutoSizeRowsMode` - how can I do?

This code can't be use at the same time, it's not working: nothing happens when using these lines of code together:

```
datagridview1.RowTemplate.Height = 50
datagridview1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
```

Comment: Are you attempting to set a minimum height of 50 while allowing the row height to exceed 50 when needed?  If so, set the [DataGridViewRow.MinimumHeight Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.minimumheight?view=netframework-4.8) to 50.

Comment: this is what i want thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a minimum height of 50 while allowing the row height to exceed 50 when needed, set the [DataGridViewRow.MinimumHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.minimumheight?view=netframework-4.8) Property to 50.

Note that if you allow new rows to be added to the DataGridView, that the new row does not appear to_copy_ the MinimumHeight property.  You can correct this by placing

```
dataGridView1.Rows(dataGridView1.NewRowIndex).MinimumHeight = 50
```

in the form's Load handler.